Cannot delete file in Windows 10
On Windows 10, there is a file [%UserProfile%\Videos\Lorem.mkv] that is less thant 9KB and I cannot delete it. The file belongs to me, I have permissions to it, there are no prompts for entering a password, etc., and ESET AV does not report any threats after scanning %UserProfile%\Videos.
I've tried deleting via these methods, with each causing Explorer/terminal freeze, or the deletion preview window to hang at 50%:

Explorer: Context Menu and Del
Terminal: cmd, powershell, and WSL

Is there any way to remove it other than a total format?

Have you already rebooted the machine and then see if it deletes after the reboot. It may still be in use by some application or program. If you have any rough idea what that program may be, look at Task Manager, Details tab, sorts by process name, and then kill the process, then try to delete the file.

What is the output of: icacls $env:UserProfile\Videos\Lorem.mkv? (Please add it to a code box within the question - PowerShell is the default terminal in Windows ≥ 10, so that's a PowerShell environment variable, whereas for cmd or Explorer it would be %UserProfile%.) This appears to be an ACL permissions issue, but if not, boot to WinRE via Shutdown /f /r /o /t 0 → Advanced → Troubleshoot → Command Prompt → DiskPart → Identify OS partition: lis vol → exit → del /f <OSpartition>:\Users\<Name>\Videos\Lorem.mkv → Verify: icacls <OSpartition>:\Users\<Name>\Videos\Lorem.mkv

Sounds like an orphan file that doesn’t actually exist on the disk.

Ramhound is correct about the orphaned file. The lorem.mkv file is most likely a sample video created by an application which was removed from the system. Orphaned files are a form of data corruption. The best way Windows has to fix corruption is the System File Checker using sfc /scannow. If this does not work, then the only other option is to backup your files and reinstall Windows.
Unless you run into other issues or SFC finds significant errors it cannot fix, then you probably do not need to reinstall Windows. If SFC finds significant issues it cannot fix, then you also must run chkdsk. chkdsk checks the file system on the storage medium for errors. chkdsk will tell you if there are issues with the storage medium, as well as attempt to repair any damage to the file system.
Think of SFC as the first check and chkdsk as the deep dive into the file system. chkdsk errors which are irreparable require reinstallation of the OS. I recommend using DiskWipe with at least three passes and then reinstalling the OS.
